# How to generate synthetic data that respects pairwise correlations of features of the real dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, synthetic-data

Let us suppose that I have a dataset with 3 features and that I know the pairwise correlations among these features.

Let us suppose that I want to build a synthetic dataset that respects those correlations, simulating the real dataset. So, I would provide fake values for one of the features and I would like to calculate te other two features from the pairwise correlations of the real dataset.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You can't *calculate* the values simply from the correlations. It may be possible to generate values.  There's a number of posts on site that explain how to simulate data to match either population or sample correlations. Presuming you want the latter, I think the sample correlation one could be adapted to specifying values for one series.

Comment: You may want to look into Metric Multi Dimensional Scaling.

Comment: Here's a search to get you started: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sample+distribution+given+correlation